# tombstoning with pivotview containing N pivot items

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot, tombstoning

I have a pivotview in which the items are created dynamically.  The views in each one is flyweight & virtualized so memory does not exceed the max allowed.  When tombstoning occurs, I save the object which the number of pivot items is based on as well as the selected index of the pivotview.  After returning to the page, the pivot items are successfully re-created, but when you set the selected index, I get an unhandled exception in App.xaml.cs that says "the parameter is incorrect"  I have verified this as the source of the exception by commenting out the line that sets the pivotview.SelectedIndex value.

any ideas as to why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the pivot's SelectedIndex can be done in the Loaded event.

This issue is documented here.

[Unhandled Exception When Setting Pivot Control SelectedItem/SelectedIndex Property to 3rd Pivot Item (WP7) | Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/604360/unhandled-exception-when-setting-pivot-control-selecteditem-selectedindex-property-to-3rd-pivot-item-wp7?wa=wsignin1.0)